# C# Picturebox.Image needs to be loaded twice before it can be used in code

Tags: c#, image, loading, picturebox

I have a picturebox on a windows form that gets filled with this command:

```
pBProcess.ImageLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(processFile) + "\\" + processes[processStep2Nr] + ".png";
```

After the images is loaded I'm trying to do two things that both only work after I loaded that image twice.

First thing:

```
Positioning.CenterHorizontally(pBProcess, pBProcess.Image.Width);
```

Which does this:

```
public static void CenterHorizontally(this Control control, int Width)
{
    Rectangle parentRect = control.Parent.ClientRectangle;
    control.Left = (parentRect.Width - Width) / 2;
}
```

and the second thing I'm trying to do is to save the image to a SQLDatabase.

```
cmdLine = "INSERT INTO " + processToSave + " (Picture) VALUES  (@Image);";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pBProcess.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdLine, connection))
{
//Parameter definieren
   sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image);
   sqlCmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = pic;
   sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Boths actions are executed correctly after I load the picturebox.image a second time.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Edit:

This is how I create the table I want to save the picture to:

```
//Tabelle wird erstellt und anschließend gefüllt
strInsert = "CREATE TABLE " + processToSave + "(Attributes NVARCHAR(50), Value TINYINT, Picture IMAGE);";
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strInsert, connection))
{
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
strInsert = "INSERT INTO " + processToSave + " (Attributes, Value) VALUES (@Attributes, @Value);";
foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strInsert, connection))
    {
        //Parameter definieren
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Attributes", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@Attributes"].Value = item.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
strInsert = "INSERT INTO " + processToSave + " (Picture) VALUES  (@Image);";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pBProcess.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strInsert, connection))
{
    //Parameter definieren
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image);
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = pic;
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And this is how I read the picture from the DB:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
strInsert = "SELECT [Picture] FROM " + processToLoad;
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand(strInsert, connection);
byte[] image = (byte[])sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar();
stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
pBProcess.Image = bitmap;
```

this is NOT working. But when I create a table in the DB called "Bilder" which has only "Picture" with DBType Image and change the code to this:

```
strInsert = "INSERT INTO Bilder (Picture) VALUES  (@Image);";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pBProcess.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strInsert, connection))
{
    //Parameter definieren
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image);
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = pic;
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

...

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
strInsert = "SELECT [Picture] FROM Bilder";
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand(strInsert, connection);
byte[] image = (byte[])sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar();
stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
pBProcess.Image = bitmap;
```

It actually works. What's wrong in my original code?

Comment: Are you perhaps loading outside of the UI thread?

Comment: It's part of a SelectionChangeCommitted Event of a combobox

Comment: Hm, still, maybe waiting for `LoadCompleted` will help?

Comment: I put the     Positioning.CenterHorizontally(pBProcess, pBProcess.Image.Width); line in that Event. That works fine. But I can not put the Database upload there too, since I'm calling it when I press a button. I also just tried the Waitonload of the picturebox. Does not help either :/

Comment: `WaitOnLoad` should help actually, imo. Did you set it to `true` before the loading so the loading gets synchronously ? As for the button: You could disable it when loading and enable in the Loadcompleted. But the real quston is: why does the take so long? Is the image so large or the disk so slow??

Comment: Yes I set it to true and put a  `MessageBox.Show("done");` right behind the loading command. The MessageBoxs pops up immediately but when I try to save the image, it fails again. What confuses me is that "pic" is actually not empty. I edited something in my startpost.

Comment: Hm, strange indeed. Btw, setting WainOnload will prevent LoadCompleted to be called. I still think it should be all that's needed. Could it be your 2nd loading is stil in the code?

Comment: @Taw I don't have a second calling in the code. I do it manually by commiting the selection change twice in a row with the same item (different item would mean different picture). When I do this, the picture gets saved into the DB correctly.

Comment: Hm, if you pick a different image, does the 1st or 2nd one get saved?

Comment: Actually I have to Select Item 1 then Item 2 and if I select Item 1 again it works (I can save Item1 Picture then). So I have to swap the picture out for another one and then back in. After that I can save it!? .. Edit: I'm going crazy, this is also inconsistent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mixing up two problems here.

The problem with

```
Positioning.CenterHorizontally(pBProcess, pBProcess.Image.Width);
```

was fixed by putting this statement into the `LoadCompleted`Event of the picturebox.

The second problem was that I actually inserted a lot of rows into my table (attributes + value) and at the end I inserted another row, consisting only of the image. When I read the table looking for the image, I only read the first row (I think) but there was no image to be found. So I changed the code, putting the image into the first row and then changing the commandline:

```
bool first = true;
foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
{
   if (first)
     cmdLine = "INSERT INTO " + processToSave + " (Attributes, Value, Picture) VALUES (@Attributes, @Value, @Image);";
   else
     cmdLine = "INSERT INTO " + processToSave + " (Attributes, Value) VALUES (@Attributes, @Value);";
   using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdLine, connection))
   {
     //Parameter definieren
     sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Attributes", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
     sqlCmd.Parameters["@Attributes"].Value = item.Text;
     sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Int);
     sqlCmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
     if (first)
     {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = pic;
        first = false;
     }
     sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```